# Pass data from plugin to frontend

Tags: magento2

Based on [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/174775/magento-2-pass-data-in-checkout) post I could pass some data to the `window.checkoutConfig`, this is great.

My problem is, that my data is dynamic and my plugin runs later when magento collects the payment methods. I want to add some extra information (shipping date) to my template file.

How can I do this, how can I access data from my plugin?

In my template file:

```
 <div class="payment-method-title field choice">
    <input type="radio"
           name="payment[method]"
           class="radio"
           data-bind="attr: {'id': getCode()}, value: getCode(), checked: isChecked, click: selectPaymentMethod, visible: isRadioButtonVisible()"/>
    <label data-bind="attr: {'for': getCode()}" class="label"><span data-bind="text: getTitle()"></span></label>
     <!-- 
     I want to put some info here from window.checkoutConfig 
     I just do not know how to pass the data after my plugins run.
     -->

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not possible.

But it was my fault. I just no need the plugin, I should do the job in the `configprovider`.